# Add translation files to custom module doesn't work

Tags: i18n-l10n

I've created translations files with poedit called nl_NL.mo and nl_NL.po and added them to a 'translations' folder within my custom module.

Now when I try to re-install my module; the translation isn't being imported.

Could this be because my default language is NL or is some other issue?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to uninstall the module completely and reinstall it again, in order to be able to import the translations. Otherwise, they are not picked up automatically. There are a couple of threads in the Drupal forums mentioning this issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/220341 , https://www.drupal.org/node/435706#comment-2711736

Hope that helps,

Comment: I've disabled the module and after that de-installed it in the de-install module page, cleared the cache and re-installed with no result.

Answer (score 0):

in

> your_module.info.yml

you must indicate the file path

```
'interface translation project': your_module
'interface translation server pattern': modules/custom/your_module/translations/amu_hal-%language.po
```